# Embedding OS variable within quoted string which is a part of linux command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

In my gitlab pipeline I want to execute the following command pattern:
`command <some-options> --filter 'eq(name,"`**`HMEQ_ABT.flw`**`")'`

Instead of static filename: **HMEQ_ABT.flw** I'd like to use the variable value e.g. **$FileName**

It should be like:

`command <some-options> --filter 'eq(name,"`**`$FileName`**`")'`

but $FileName is not substituted with HMEQ_ABT.flw value.

How can insert variable name to get its value instead, please?

Comment: You need double quotes instead of single; single quotes preserve everything between them completely verbatim. Then, you need to escape the literal double quotes inside the string. `command <some-options> --filter "eq(name,\"$FileName\")"` (or `command <some-options> --filter "eq(name,\" $FileName \")"` if you really want spaces inside the quotes, but that seems implausible, in spite of your examples).

Comment: @tripleee
Thanks a lot, I was so close ;)